# One repository with two folder names

Tags: python

I have a series of numerical computations that use python scripts in the /src folder and they take many hours to complete.

In the mean time, I would like to add more features in the folder or debug the existing files, without breaking the code that is currently running.

I was thinking about creating a remote git repository and clone it to two different directories:

```
/src/lib.py
/dev/lib.py
```

I push from `dev` to `remote` and pull from `remote` to `src`

And in the main code `main.py` I have:

```
from lib import foo
foo()
```

How do I tell the release code to load the libraries from `/src` while the development code to load from /dev without changing the `main.py` code?

Is there a better way (other than git) to synchronize these two folders?

Comment: Why not include the main.py in the repo and copy it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than thinking about it in terms of folder naming while using Git, you might be better of using branches in Git. This tutorial is pretty good. The graphics are overly busy, but basically just create a 'develop' branch and use the default branch 'master' for production.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

> Is there a better way (other than git) to synchronize these two folders?

There are lots of ways :) like `rsync` or `cp -R`, etc. But using Git is probably going to help you more, after the initial setup.